# Деструктор и Конструктор

Tags: c++, ооп

Зачем компилятор по дефолту создает конструктор? Он же нужен, чтобы инициализировать поля, но если я не хочу инициализировать, зачем он создает конструктор(конструктор по-умолчанию)?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100091/discussion-on-question-by-kaylil-01---).

Answer (score 1):

Если в классе не определен ни один конструктор, компилятор создает сам конструктор по умолчанию. В этом автоматически созданном конструкторе вызываются конструкторы по умолчанию для всех базовых классов и полей.Если в этом классе нет полей, то их инициализация не производится, и выделяется память только под размер класса.

Comment: "...и выделяется память только под размер класса"? Конструктор не имеет никакого отношения к "выделению памяти под размер класса". К тому моменту, когда начинают работать конструкторы, память уже давно выделена.